# Select Pandas dataframe rows based on round hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

my dataframe's index is intervaled every 3min :

```
Timestamp                value
2019-06-30 07:00:00    0.065248
2019-06-30 07:03:00    0.067896
2019-06-30 07:06:00    0.070529
2019-06-30 07:09:00    0.073034
2019-06-30 07:12:00    0.085928
                         ...   
2019-06-30 16:48:00    0.246681
2019-06-30 16:51:00    0.246745
2019-06-30 16:54:00    0.247110
2019-06-30 16:57:00    0.247174
2019-06-30 17:00:00    0.246338
```

I need to select every round hour for a line plot.

My stupid solution is:

```
hour_ls = ['2019-06-30 07:00:00', '2019-06-30 08:00:00','2019-06-30 09:00:00','2019-06-30 10:00:00',
           '2019-06-30 11:00:00','2019-06-30 12:00:00','2019-06-30 13:00:00','2019-06-30 14:00:00',
           '2019-06-30 13:00:00','2019-06-30 16:00:00','2019-06-30 17:00:00']

hour_ls = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in hour_ls]
df.loc[hour_ls]
```

Is there a pythonic\pandeic why of doing this cleanly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `floor` to find the hours and then check if the index is equal to the hour:

```
df[df.index == df.index.floor('H')]
```

Comment: How would you iterate the dates as well?

Comment: if you want round use: `df[df.index == df.index.round('H')]`. This will by default do what you need for entire data frame. No need for loops. You can now plot the resulting value column.

Comment: iterate for what purpose? Generally you should avoid iterating on dataframe, but if you do: `for date in df.index():`?

Answer (score 0):

After converting the column into [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) elements you now have access to datetime.minute. Example: Given you have a dataframe df as given above:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
hourly_entries = pd.DataFrame([el for el in df['Timestamp'] if el.minute == 0])
```

This will  create a new DataFrame named 'hourly_entries' that will contain all elements with datetime.minute == 0.